# Почему не находит ключ в словаре?

Tags: python, json, словари, анализ-данных

У меня есть JSON файл со списком операций, в нём их около 100. У каждой операции есть время совершения, которое находится по ключу `date`. Мне надо отсортировать эти операции по дате.

Я написал код, но почему-то он работает только, если операций около 60. На примерно 80 операциях появляется ошибка что такого ключа, как `date`, не существует.

```
import json

with open("operations.json", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    operations_json = f.read()

operations = json.loads(operations_json)
sorted_operations = sorted(operations, key = lambda k: k['date'])

print(sorted_operations)
```

[Файл JSON с операциями](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/A8RqarPdSGXcgQ)

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Элементарный способ проверки данных:

```
In [255]: [(i,x) for i,x in  enumerate(operations) if "date" not in x]
Out[255]: [(74, {})]
```

Т.е. элемент списка с индексом 74 - пустой словарь

---

исправленное решение:

```
sorted_operations = sorted(filter(None, operations), key = lambda k: k['date'])
```